# hiding files using gitignore

Tags: javascript, git, github, gitignore

I want to hide the node_modules folder and a javascript file in git,for which I added the following in **.gitignore** file :

```
          node_modules/
          database.js/
```

After that,in git bash I added the following commands

```
          git rm -r --cached .
          git add .
          git commit -m "hide files"
          git push origin master
```

But I was able to hide only node_modules folder and not the js file.Please don't mistake me, I am a newbie to git. What is my mistake here?Can anybody help? Thank you

Comment: You need to remove the trailing slash from your JS file, that's only for folders. ([see the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_examples))

Answer (score 3):

You have a trailing slash behind `database.js`

```
database.js/
```

It should simply be

```
database.js
```

Please refer to the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format).